# glib dbus service example using dbus-binding-tool?

Tags: glib, dbus

I'm looking for a full example using the glib dbus support suggested by Freedesktop.org here (http://www.freedesktop.org/wiki/Software/DBusBindings/), and dbus-binding-tool.

I looked here, https://developer.gnome.org/gio/2.26/GDBusServer.html, but this isn't using a server header file generated by dbus-binding-tool and also looked here, http://dbus.freedesktop.org/doc/dbus-tutorial.html#glib-server, but this tutorial is using the deprecated dbus-glib interface...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like you need `gdbus-codegen`, for which there is a full tutorial in [the man page](https://developer.gnome.org/gio/stable/gdbus-codegen.html).

Comment: This is correct. It was confusing to me as to why there are multiple dbus implementations. The glib one is much nicer to use than the dbus one imo.